# linear mixed model for unbalanced nested design

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have the following data set collected from my experimental design. I have two species (sp1 and sp2), in sp1 I have two accessions (a1 and a2) which are different types of material (L and CV), and then in each accession, I randomly took two seeds (1 and 2) and after growing I generated two clones from each seed (1 and 2) and I did the same for a2. In the dataset, I have another species sp2 which only has one accession (a3) but the same cloning was done for this species also.

As far as I know, this type of experimental design is named as **unbalanced nested design**, in which factors don't have the same levels as factorial or other balanced designs.
Now I want to perform an analysis of variance to get the following results:

1: analysis of variance so that **accession is nested in species** and to see the differences between species based on measured traits Y1 and Y2 and then relevant plot with Duncan grouping letters.

2: a plot of comparing two species while different types (L, CV, and W) are also represented  (are grouped). I really appreciated it if you could help me. Thanks a lot.

```
df <- data.frame(species=c(rep("sp1",8),rep("sp2",4)), 
            accession=c(rep("a1",4),rep("a2",4), rep("a3", 4)),
           type=c(rep("L",4),rep("CV",4), rep("W", 4)),
           seed=c(rep("1",2),rep("2",2), rep("1", 2), rep("2", 2),
                  rep("1", 2), rep("2", 2)),
           clone=c(rep("1",1),rep("2",1), rep("1", 1), rep("2", 1),
                   rep("1", 1), rep("2", 1), rep("1",1),rep("2",1), rep("1", 1), rep("2", 1),
                   rep("1", 1), rep("2", 1)),
           Y1 = c(11, 10, 8, 9, 20, 21, 19, 19, 6, 5, 7, 8),
           Y2 = c(34, 31, 23, 25, 44, 45, 33, 34, 14, 11, 16, 13))
```

Comment: what are "Duncan grouping letters"?

Comment: We use Duncan test to see if the difference between pairs of treatment is significant or not and in case of significance they get different letters.

Answer (score 2):

As a start:

first with `lme4`/`lmerTest` (the latter is needed for p-values on the fixed effects)

```r
library(lmerTest)
summary(lmer(Y1 ~ species + (1|species:accession), data = df),
   ddf = "Kenward-Roger")
```

Results:

```r
Random effects:
 Groups            Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 species:accession (Intercept) 52.178   7.223
 Residual                       1.417   1.190
Number of obs: 12, groups:  species:accession, 3

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error     df t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   14.625      5.125  1.000   2.854    0.215
speciessp2    -8.125      8.877  1.000  -0.915    0.528
```

Now with `nlme`:

```r
library(nlme)
## we have to do a bit of data transformation to make this work
df <- transform(df, sp_acc = interaction(species, accession))
dfg <- groupedData(Y1 ~ 1|sp_acc, df)
summary(lme(Y1 ~ species, random = ~ 1, data = dfg))
```

```r
Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | sp_acc
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    7.223371 1.190238

Fixed effects:  Y1 ~ species
             Value Std.Error DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept) 14.625   5.12500  9  2.8536585  0.0190
speciessp2  -8.125   8.87676  1 -0.9153114  0.5281
```

Most results match between the two packages (estimate of among-accession and residual variance; estimates and standard errors for fixed effects; denominator df and p-value for `speciesp2`). The only difference is in the estimated df/p-value for the intercept, which is probably not scientifically important (i.e., testing whether `Y1` is significant different from zero for species 1).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben to answer the question.